# using my custom font in other android apps

Tags: android, fonts

I know I can use a custom font in my app, but I wanted to know if there is a way 
to save the font with my app to a particular place in the android file system
so that other apps could use it by load it from the file system.
If not may I use it as a service app that run in the background of the device and give the font by network to all the other android apps that are running.

Thanks in advance,
Shahar.

Comment: Do you want to override the system default font?

Or are you writing these other apps and want to share assets between them?

Comment: I'm writing several apps and I want to share the font created by one of them with all the others.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can store the fonts in asset folder and load in textview by using below method

```
TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.custom); 
  Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/HandmadeTypewriter.ttf"); 
  tv.setTypeface(face);
```

Comment: Yup, this works. As per your other question, Shahar, no, you will not be able to provision the font to other applications, only your own.

Comment: and for the other possible method - can I send it through the network so that the source is current device and destination is current device which I am the sender and other apps are the receivers (send from myself to myself)??